# "Best of" style questions

Tags: discussion

Long ago, I asked this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234/best-asp-net-e-commerce-framework-aspdotnetstorefront-ablecommerce-bvcommerce/3551132#3551132, about the best asp.net E-Commerce framework.

I'm now wishing I had asked it a bit differently because I would like the answers to be more oriented around specific products. It seems it'd be best if there were 1 answer per product and then people would vote/against for their favorite product and all product discussion would happen in comments.

Is stackoverflow not the place to do this style?
Should I modify my question to try to acheive this?
Should I change the question to a Community Wiki and then make changes?

Comment: IMHO, there's a more subtle problem with "best of" questions that can be hard to correct after you've encountered it: they're lazy, and they collect lazy answers. You probably don't care that JoeBloggs thinks EZStorFrunt is the best; you want to know *why he thinks it would be **best for you**...* assuming that's actually what he thinks. I've watched a couple of users go around link-spamming their own products on "best of" questions now, fully confident that they'll be safe because their answers, useless and self-serving though they are, do fall within the meager guidelines provided...

Comment: Sure... I suppose what I'm really after is people's experiences, both positive and negative, with the products out there. I wouldn't expect anyone to make their decision based on this type of thread, but I do think it can be an effective way to find options you hadn't considered, raise new questions you need to ask in the evaluation of products, and point out products with major deficiencies.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow is a place for questions that have a finite number of objective answers.  It's almost always the wrong place to ask for the "Best of [whatever]," because most of the time, people have different opinions about what is best, and there isn't a defensibly right or wrong answer.

People sometimes mark questions like this CW, but that's not what CW is for and it doesn't make those questions okay.  CW status should be used when you want the entire community to participate in editing a post to make it better, as you might do for a FAQ page.  CW status takes away rep gain because it makes no sense for a post owned by the whole community to earn rep for one specific user.  It was never intended to legitimize subjective/discussion questions.

There's nothing wrong with asking people to discuss pros and cons of ASP e-commerce solutions; it's just that Stack Overflow isn't the place to do it.  Since you're willing to modify your question, you could, for example, ask about how to integrate an e-commerce product with your existing code.

Comment: +1 for proper exposition of CW.